# JS wait for callback to complete execution inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, pouchdb

I am having an array which consist of 3 data which I need to insert in `pouchdb`, so I'm using a `for loop` to insert the data, but the problem is it is not inserting complete data because the loop finishes before callback.

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   var jsondoc=doc1;//document
    console.log(i)  //getting console for all data. eg:1,2,3
    console.log(data[i])//getting console for all data. eg:hi, hello

    jsondoc.messages.push({msg: data[i]});   //updating message, here need to be done somthing           
                      db.put(jsondoc, function(err2, response2){
                         if (err2) { console.log(JSON.stringify(err2)); }
                            console.log("this is not repeating") ;                                    
                       });

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you'd want the `loop` to not finish before the inserts finished?

Comment: `if (jsondoc.messages.length === data.length - 1) {db.put()}` ?

Comment: No there is no particular reason for using for loop  @Cristik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `db insertion` runs async, you cannot put the loop on hold until the operation completes. One thing that you can do is to serialise the `db inserts` with a helper function like this:

```
function insertItem(data, i, completeCallback) {
    // check if we still have items to send
    if(i < data.length) {
        var jsondoc=doc1;//document
        //updating message, here need to be done somthing
        jsondoc.messages.push({msg: data[i]});   
        db.put(jsondoc, function(err2, response2){
            if (err2) { 
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err2)); 
            } 
            // recursively call to push the next message
            insertItem(data, i+1, completeCallback);
        });
    } else {
        // no more items to send, execute the callback
        if(typeof completeCallback === "function") {
            completeCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to update your code so that instead of continuing the execution after the call of the function, to pass that code into the callback of the `pushMessage` function, so if your original code looks like this:

```
// ... code before the loop
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    // ... original body of the loop
}
// ... code to execute after the loop and that currently causes problems
```

you'll need to change it like this:

```
// ... original code that was before the loop
insertItem(data, 0, function() {
    // ... original code hat was executed after the loop and that caused problems
    // but now it gets executed after all items were inserted in db
}
```

Another alternative would be to send all inserts in parallel and perform a `join()` on those operations; you'll still need the callback workaround though. Something along the lines:

```
function insertItems(data, callback) {
    var remainingItems = data.length;
    if(remainingItems === 0 && typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }         
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var jsondoc=doc1;//document
        console.log(i)  //getting console for all data. eg:1,2,3
        console.log(data[i])//getting console for all data. eg:hi, hello

        jsondoc.messages.push({msg: data[i]});   //updating message, here need to be done somthing           
        db.put(jsondoc, function(err2, response2){
            if (err2) { console.log(JSON.stringify(err2)); }
            remainingItems--;
            if(remainingItems === 0 && typeof callback === "function") {
                // I know, code redundancy :P
                callback();
            }                                     
        });

    }
}
```

The usage of this second function is the same as for `insertItem`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is a scoping issue. jsondoc or data[i], or whichever variable is causing the problem, is changed before your callback can complete.

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szvo2sot/), which shows how to solve such a scoping problem.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    (function(){
        var j = i;
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(j)
        }, 500);
    })();
}
```

If you look at your js console when the jsFiddle runs you'll see that the first loop prints 3 times 3, which is the finishing value for i. While the second, where we store the value to a new variable inside a new scope, outputs 1, 2, 3 as expected.